# Redundant curly braces around a hash parameter for Rubocop in rails

Tags: ruby, rubocop

After doing `bundle exec rubocop -p` for this perticular line I am getting offense.

```
 post = current_timeline.posts.build(post_params.merge({ avatars: params[:avatars] }))
```

The offense is: `Style/BracesAroundHashParameters: Redundant curly braces around a hash parameter.`

How to fix it? I am new to rubocop in ruby.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply remove redundant curly braces:

```
post = current_timeline.posts.build(post_params.merge(avatars: params[:avatars]))
```

They are not needed for the last argument passed into a method being `Hash` literal.